# What is the condition for a turning point in GR?

Tags: general-relativity, classical-mechanics

In classical mechanics in 1D the condition for a turning point is given by $E = U$ where $E$ is the energy of the particle and $U$ is the potential energy. What is the corresponding condition for a turning point in GR? I suspect it will be different when caused by a first rank and second rank tensor? (feel free to explain both cases)

Comment: Hi More Anonymous. Turning point of what?

Comment: @Qmechanic a point particle (will do for illustrative purposes)

Comment: Maybe start by defining a turning point in classical mechanics in $d>1$?

Comment: @Qmechanic can't the problem always be reduced to $1$D by merely going into the particle's reference frame?

Comment: If you're looking for velocity being $u = 0$, that would mean setting 4-velocity to $(c, 0)$.